# How to change active color of bootstrap button in group of classes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, uibutton

i have a button in span with group of classes "btn btn-info btn-lg", i want to change the color of button for that i have added another class "btn btn-info btn-lg filterBtn". It's working for normal state but when i click button the active state of button not changing.

```
<span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg searchbarbtn" type="button" title="Filter" id="filterbtn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#filterpanel">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter"></i>
    </button>
 </span>
```